# After Snowflake task ownership transfer it removes AFTER keyword from TASK definition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

TASK1 and TASK2 Definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK1
  warehouse = 'WH'
  schedule = '5 minute'
as
CALL SCHEMA.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE1('ARG1');

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK2
  warehouse = 'WH'
  after TASK1
as
CALL SCHEMA.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE2('ARG1');
```

I am trying to transfer ownership of TASK1 AND TASK2 to role ROLE1

```
grant ownership on task TASK1 to role ROLE1;
```

When I ran above command it removes AFTER keyword (after TASK1) line and definition of TASK1 and TASK2 looks like following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK1
  warehouse = 'WH'
  schedule = '5 minute'
as
CALL SCHEMA.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE1('ARG1');

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK2
  warehouse = 'WH'
as
CALL SCHEMA.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE2('ARG1');
```

How do I make sure It will add dependency task as well when I am transferring ownership.
I don't want to do it manually using following command

```
alter task TASK2 add after TASK1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A task cannot have a predecessor which they do not share the same owner role:

```
use role accountadmin;
create or replace role test_role;
grant usage on procedure test_sp(varchar) to role test_role;
grant usage on warehouse gokhan_wh to role test_role;
grant usage on database gokhan_db to role test_role;
grant all on schema gokhan_db.public to role test_role;
grant role test_role to user gokhan;

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK1
  warehouse = 'GOKHAN_WH'
  schedule = '5 minute'
as
CALL test_sp('ARG1');

use role test_role;

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK2
  warehouse = 'GOKHAN_WH'
  after TASK2
as
CALL test_sp('ARG1');
```

The second one will fail with "Invalid predecessor TASK1 was specified".

As you change the ownership one by one, you break the relation because they belong to different roles! To prevent breaking the relation, you may change ownership of all tasks in the schema:

```
grant ownership on all TASKS in schema public to role ROLE1;
```

So in your case, there is no simple workaround. You may consider writing a JS procedure to automatically re-connect these tasks.